# Listen to Mediaplayer completion from different class

Tags: java, android

I am using Mediaplayer in Class A and create instance of A in class B. How can I notify class B, when Mediaplayer has stopped. Since I am doing this in Android , I want to avoid heap issue.

```
 class A {
  //Mediaplayer plays and stops

  //oncompletion notify class B

 }

class B {
 A objOfA = new A();

 //do something when Mediaplayer in A has stopped.
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalBroadcastManager. Simply send a broadcast from your mediaplayeractivity and then listen in B

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/